# Voronoi Cell of the Dual Lattice?

Tags: duality-theorems, polyhedra, integer-lattices

A lattice is a discrete (we may assume full-rank) subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$, often written as the image of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ under a particular matrix $\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (a *basis* of the lattice).

Associated with any lattice $L$ are two different objects:

1. The *Voronoi cell* of $L$: $\mathcal{V}_L = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n \mid \forall \ell\in L\setminus \{0\}, \|x\|_2^2 < \|x - \ell\|_2^2\}$
2. The *Dual lattice* of $L$: $L^\vee = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n \mid \forall \ell\in L, \langle \ell, x\rangle \in\mathbb{Z}\}$

As the dual lattice is itself a lattice, it has its own Voronoi cell $\mathcal{V}_{L^\vee}$. There are known relationships between $\mathcal{V}_L$ and $\mathcal{V}_{L^\vee}$. In particular, it is known that:

$$\mathsf{vol}(\mathcal{V}_L)\mathsf{vol}(\mathcal{V}_{L^\vee}) = 1$$

There are other somewhat deeper relationships known between various numerical quantities related to the Voronoi cell of the primal and dual lattices such as *transference theorems*.
One famous one is that:
$$1 \leq \lambda_1(L)\rho(L^\vee) \leq n$$
(I may be missing some constant factors) where $\lambda_1(L)$ is (a scaling of) the inradius of $\mathcal{V}_L$ and $\rho(L^\vee)$ is the circumradius of $\mathcal{V}_{L^\vee}$.
My question is:

> Are "non-numeric" relationships known between $\mathcal{V}_L$ and $\mathcal{V}_{L^\vee}$?

By this, I mean ways of using knowledge of $\mathcal{V}_L$ (as a polyhedron) to determine attributes of $\mathcal{V}_{L^\vee}$ (as a polyhedron) that aren't simply relationships between $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions of the polyhedra.
For example, if one could use knowledge of the location of the vertices of $\mathcal{V}_L$ to determine the vertices of $\mathcal{V}_{L^\vee}$.

Comment: In physics what you call the dual lattice is called the [reciprocal lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_lattice), and the Voronoi cell the [Wigner Seitz cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Seitz_cell). I am sure much is known about these, for example one can classify all (Bravais) lattices in 2 and 3 dimensions (and presumably higher), there are only a finite number of them. Some interesting special cases are that the cubic lattices are dual to themselves, the triangular lattice is dual to itself, and the FCC and BCC are dual to each other.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am interested in high dimensional lattices, where the classification problem is quite open (although I believe for each fixed dimension "mass formula" give finiteness results. The finite numbers grow quite rapidly though). One can view this question as asking "if I am willing to put in the work to characterize the voronoi cell of a particular lattice, do I get a characterization of the voronoi cell of a second lattice (the dual) 'for free' by general theory? If not, do I get some partial characterization?"